# Allow Guest Mode (no authorization) in Custom Authorizer in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, serverless

I'm trying to find a way to allow *guest mode* in custom authorizer in AWS.

Basically, what I want to achieve is the following scenario:

- if there is no `Authorization` header in request then trigger lambda function that responds with some data
- if there is `Authorization` header then my custom authorizer should check JWT token and either `Allow` or `Deny`. Then trigger lambda if `custom-authorizer` returned `Allow`

I see I can achieve either but not both, i.e. I can open the endpoint (remove `authorizer` completely) which works okay or I can put `authorizer` which again works okay.

Yet, I don't see a way to by-pass `custom-authorizer` when there is no `Authorization` header.

Example configuration in serverless:

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - http:
          path: /hello
          method: get
          private: true
          authorizer:
            identitySource: method.request.header.Authorization # Can this be optional?
            name: custom-authorizer
  custom-authorizer:
    handler: authorizer.handler
```

From my testing I can confirm that once `authorization` is there and there is no `Authorization` header in request then my `custom-authorizer` is not triggered at all and API gateway responds straight away with `401 Unauthorized`.

Please take into account that in my guest mode I **don't** want to get custom API gateway response (this is possible and works). I want to trigger lambda function just like there was no authorization at all.

I'm coming to conclusion this is impossible and the only workaround is to remove `authorization` and then do some custom code in lambda.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on @fedonev answer here is the complete solution:

- Use `HTTP API` instead of `REST API`.
- Update `custom-authorizer`

Let's start with updating `serverless.yml` accordingly to the newer and *different* HTTP API syntax:

Replace `events.http` with `events.httpApi` and add `httpApi.authorizer` to `provider`. Updated `serverless.yml`:

```yaml
provider:
  httpApi:                          # Added
    authorizers:
      customAuthorizer:
        type: request
        functionName: custom-authorizer

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:                    # Changed
          path: /hello
          method: get
          authorizer:
            name: customAuthorizer  # Changed

custom-authorizer:
  handler: authorizer.handler
```

Next, we need to update our authorizer handler function as well. It still needs to return policy as it was doing with REST API. Yet... there is no `event.authorizationToken` and no `event.methodArn` anymore (I left it commented out for reference):

```js
module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  if (
    !event.headers.authorization ||
    event.headers.authorization === 'Bearer ABCDEF'
  ) {
    // if (event.authorizationToken === 'Bearer ABCDEF')
    return {
      principalId: 'anonymous',
      policyDocument: {
        Version: '2012-10-17',
        Statement: [
          {
            Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
            Effect: 'Allow',
            Resource: event.routeArn,
            // Resource: event.methodArn,
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  }
  throw Error('Unauthorized');
};
```

Now, we can see we have a full control over authorization and we can check if the token is there: `!event.headers.authorization` (this simulates guest mode) or if token is valid: `event.headers.authorization === 'Bearer ABCDEF'`. If the token is invalid we throw error which gives `401 Unauthorized` as expected.

Finally, worth noting is that all `headers` keys are lowercased and `principalId` is mandatory (as previously, when using REST API, authorizer worked without it).

Deploy and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your [sls event handler](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/http-api) as `httpApi`<sup>*</sup>, rather than `http`, then `identitySource` is an optional input to `authorizer` (assuming the serverless api matches the AWS api).

The relevant CloudFormation `AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Authorizer` docs are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigatewayv2-authorizer.html).

As you experienced, if `identitySource` is configured but not present in the client request, Apig returns `401`.  If you omit `identitySource` from the config, all requests will be sent to your authoriser lambda.  Your lambda can then handle the three cases:  no token, bad token, good token.

<sup>*</sup> `httpApi` deploys as `ApiGatewayV2` in AWS CloudFormation.  V2 is, as the Serverless docs say, "faster and cheaper than v1".  The api and [feature set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html) differ somewhat between the "HTTP Api" (V2) "Rest Api" (V1), but `httpApi` is a good default choice.

Comment: This `httpApi` looks very promising. Yet, simple change from `http` to `httpApi` leads to `Event references not configured authorizer 'custom-authorizer'` error.

There seems to be a bit more configuration changes required. Overall, good tip!

Comment: There are more people noticing there is a newer syntax for `httpApi`: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/8781#issuecomment-895599718

Answer (score 0):

One solution not mentioned here is that you can choose to send up a custom Authorization header with unauthenticated requests (i.e. `Authentication: "UNAUTHENTICATED"`), and then evaluate requests with that specific header as unauthenticated.

This requires coordination with the frontend, but side-steps the 401 and allows you to still pass through context to the downstream API.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit similar situation with REST API and Lambda Authorizer. My authorizer was configured as request authorizer and I specified "authorization" as required header. This means that API Gateway will not invoke the authorizer if the header is missing.

To allow anonymous access I changed the header from "authorization" to "host" and now API Gateway passes all requests to the authorizer.
I hope this helps.